# matlab not working properly, 'ver' comes up with undef function errors

Tags: windows, matlab

I've been trying to get my installation of matlab working but for some reason even the simplest functions don't work.

When I call 'ver'

I get the error:
Undefined function 'ismembc' for input type double...

I assume that there is something wrong with my installation, but exactly what? How can I trouble shoot this?

the problem is that I've installed it on a portable SSD. The SSD runs matlab perfectly fine on my 64bit laptop. It just hasmajor problems with a 32bit desktop. My version of matlab comes with both 64 and 32 bit directories.

Comment: Maybe try un-installing and re-installing ?

Comment: @PaulR the problem is that I've installed it on a portable SSD. The SSD runs matlab perfectly fine on my 64bit laptop. It's just have major problems with a 32bit desktop. My version of matlab comes with both 64 and 32 bit directories.

Comment: Is this Windows or Linux ? Either way you should probably tag it as such and also add the info about the SSD and your two systems etc to your question

Answer (score 0):

`ismembc` is a mex-function, which means it's a 32-bit/64-bit problem. You need to install the 32-bit and 64-bit versions separately, or just the 32-bit version.